# Google app engine QR code decoder

Tags: python, google-app-engine, qr-code

I was wondering if there is a good library for python for decoding QR code. Basically what I would like is to give library image with QR code on it and the library would output contents saved in image.

Comment: Decoding a QR code on a webserver is a rather unusual thing to want to do. What's your use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked before with no success. Two problems are that native c code can't be compiled and you can't get access to the file system.

pyqrcode didn't work out and neither did zxing.

Comment: I have edited my answer for a pure python implementation. Does this work for you?

Comment: @Matt this didnt work for me neither ... i guess i'll have to write my own code than :)

Comment: also, I wouldn't mind if you checked the checkbox saying this is the correct answer ;)

Comment: Sure thing ... just started on it ... first the reading part and then coding ... i'll put my progress here and i'll share the code with you ...

Answer (score 3):

Have you already looked at : http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/

If code compiling does not work for you, then there is also pure python implementation at : http://github.com/hcvst/pyqr

Comment: Does `pyqr` support decoding?

Answer (score 2):

If you're still looking for something to do this a year later, you should check the ZBar project at http://zbar.sourceforge.net/. It looks like it started out for 1-D barcodes but has been expanded to include QR. It's implemented in C, LGPL licensed, and in addition to source has binaries for Linux, Windows and iPhone. Bindings available for Python, Perl, Ruby.

As of August 17, 2011 the core image processing portion of ZBar hasn't been updated since 2009 but there is recent activity on the iPhone development part of the project, which I'll interpret as the core being stable. There's also some activity in the SourceForge forums for the project.

It's also possible that pyxing (https://github.com/holizz/pyxing) would work but all that's there is an initial checkin of the port, so it's up to the (possible) user to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [qrtools](http://zleap.net/python-qr-code-reader/)
, It has a nice enough interface

```
from qrtools import QR
myCode = QR(filename=u"/home/psutton/Documents/Python/qrcodes/qrcode.png")
if myCode.decode():
  print myCode.data
  print myCode.data_type
```

Output

```
123456
text
```