# Library for encoding and decoding QR Codes using Python

Tags: python, qr-code

Is there any library in python for encoding and decoding qr codes. i have searched some old questions in stackoverflow but some links are dead and some links they have given were not working. suggest me for any python working qr-code library.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602645/google-app-engine-qr-code-decoder ?

Comment: tried all the things but no luck .... tried qrtools,pyqrcodec and qrcode in git

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode. It only works for generation of codes though.

Answer (score 1):

Try [pyqrnative](http://code.google.com/p/pyqrnative/). It's not really actively being developed, but does what it should do. The main issue with it is that the documentation is kind of non-existent. A very brief example can be seen in the project's test code, while [ros.org](http://www.ros.org/doc/unstable/api/pyqrnative/html/namespacepyqrnative.html) has generated an overview of the available classes and functions.

Answer (score 0):

A new kid on the block : http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/ . Must compile to have it but seems good.